# Who is being addressed in Matthew 6:13?

Tags: matthew, satan, lords-prayer

In Matthew's description of the Lord's Prayer, he quotes Jesus telling people to pray to "our Father" but at [6:13](http://biblehub.com/matthew/6-13.htm) the prayer states: "Lead us not into temptation...."  Who is being addressed here?  Does the prayer ask God not to lead us into temptation?  Does this mean that God sometimes causes people to be tempted to sin?  If so, doesn't that really follow the Jewish concept that God Himself, or through His agents (e.g. Satan) create temptation to make it possible for men to use their free will and make appropriate choices?  See Deut. 30:15-20 (stating that God created good and evil so that man should choose good); Job 1:12 (Satan testing Job on God's orders); Isaiah 45:7 (God creates good and evil).

Comment: I would argue that God created everything good, but allows men the ability to choose evil. Isa. 45:7 can be translated "calamity", which is God's judgment against evil.

Comment: "Peirasmon" means trial, certainly something Jesus was led into the wilderness to be tried (peirasthEnai). I find nowhere God tempts a man with evi, "lLet no man say when he is tempted, I am tempted of God: for God cannot be tempted with evil, neither tempteth he any man."(James 1:13)

Comment: @user2479  The word "ra" used in Isaiah 45:7 is the same as I Deut. 30:15-20 where G-d says He put good and evil before us.  To translate it as calamity in Isaiah is being self-deceptive.  Also look at Job.  If you don't think G-d creates evil, if only to provide choices an enhance free will, then you believe in Dualism, meaning that you implicitly believe in 2 gods.

Comment: That a Good God, who saw all He created was good, including giving man the ability to choose "life and blessing, or death and cursing"(Dt. 30:19) does not translate into "Dualism". Case in point: Moses told the children of Israel they would abandon God and walk after idols(Dt. 31:29), did that remove the obligation from Israel to obey the Law? Wasn't the Law "good", and their choice to obey it "good" also? The fact that they disobeyed it did not make the Law evil, rather it shows the mercy of God giving them a choice to obey the Law from their heart.

Answer (score 3):

According to Matthew, this is part of the Sermon on the Mount which begins in 5:1 and continues through the end of Matthew 7. In 5:1, Matthew states: "[Now when Jesus saw the crowds, he went up on a mountainside and sat down. His disciples came to him, 2 and he began to teach them.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5&version=NASB)" so we can conclude that according to the author of Matthew that this is written to the Disciples.

Luke 11 also provides an answer in verse 1 which states "[One day Jesus was praying in a certain place. When he finished, one of his disciples said to him, 'Lord, teach us to pray, just as John taught his disciples.'](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+11&version=NASB)"

The Greek lexicon for [lead](http://biblehub.com/greek/1533.htm) and [into](http://biblehub.com/greek/1519.htm) would tend to indicate that this might be consistent with the concept of Satan as an agent of God - like the reciprocal of a defense attorney who defends a guilty man. In spite of this, I think the emphasis here is less on God as guide and more on God as the deliverer - in this case from Evil. I don't think you can really use this as a silver bullet one way or the other on the idea of God or an agent of God as tempter, as good arguments could be made both ways like has been done above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when Evil is not classified correctly. For there are two classifications. "The Knowledge of Good and Evil" in this classification Evil is used as meaning "Dysfunction" in Deuteronomy 30:15-20 however Evil is used as allowing the knowledge of Dysfunction to change your mood. See it was not that Adam and Eve never made mistakes. Those mistakes never bothered them till they ate of the fruits which is sin. Faith in Hope, corrects this argument starter.

**In Matthew 6:13 leading us not into temptation can be understood by what God told Cain**

> If you do well, will you not be accepted? And if you do not do well, sin lies at the door. And its desire is for you, but you should rule over it.” (Genesis 4:7 NKJV)

So the error is not the sin, not doing well is not the sin, but it is when we realize that we are in error that sin lies at the door, when we receive the knowledge of evil, the knowledge of the dysfunction that sin lies at the door.

So this is an instead of statement. Instead of my natural choice which is to worry, get angry, or depressed about the error, Deliver us from our error. That is Faith, the Hope that God can deliver us from our error. Faith applies to "when" we receive the knowledge of the error.

And all of this is addressed to "the Father" as it plainly states. God never wants us to Sin he wants to lead us away from Sin.